# How do COM Interface pointers relate to the implementing class?

Tags: c++, windows, com

Say I have a COM Interface pointer

```
IMyInterface *pInterface = 0x12696340;
```

I can see from the debugger by following the function call that this must be implemented by CMyImplementer, but that class is at 0x12686e50.

My question is, how does COM relate the interface to the implementing class? There must be some way to convert from the interface to the class pointer - how would one do that?

Comment: `There must be some way to convert from the interface to the class pointer` Why must there be? For all you know, the COM object is implemented in, say, Visual Basic and there is no such thing as a "class" behind it. What do you think you need this information for? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happens, in one implementation I'm familiar with. Not sure how universal this layout is but it may give you an idea of what is possible.

The layout of the class in memory, in 32-bit mode, looks like this:

```
[ (4 bytes) ptr to vtable for IUnknown ]
[ (4 bytes) ptr to vtable for IDispatch ]
[ (4 bytes) ptr to vtable for IMyInterface ]     <--- pInterface points to here
[ (....) member variables of the class implementing CoYourClass etc. ]
```

Elsewhere in memory (one instance of this for all objects of the class):

```
[ (12 bytes) vtable for CoYourClass::IUnknown ]
[ (28 bytes) vtable for CoYourClass::IDispatch ]
[ (4*n bytes) vtable for CoYourClass::IMyInterface ]    <---- (*pInterface) points here
```

The entries in the vtable point to thunks. When you call `pInterface->Foo();`, the vtable entry corresponding to `Foo` is retrieved, which is the code address of a thunk. That thunk receives `pInterface` as its `this` pointer.  The thunk knows that it is an IMyInterface thunk within a CoYourClass class and it subtracts the fixed offset of `8` bytes in this case to retrieve a pointer to the start of the object. Then the thunk calls the actual code you've written to implement `Foo`, passing the adjusted pointer as `this`.

Note to OP: You could figure out the layout your compiler uses by inspecting memory and variables in your debugger as you call an object (easiest if your debugger lets you step from the client code into the server code for in-process object)

Comment: vtable itself is not part of the object instance, only vtable pointer is.

Comment: Actually, `pInterface` points to the four bytes that themselves point to `IMyInterface` vtable. The way you have it, there could never be two distinct `IMyInterface` pointers referring to two distinct `CoYourClass` instances (since all `CoYourClass` instances share the same vtable). This is all assuming a textbook "class derived from interface" implementation. There are many other possible implementation techniques.

Comment: 0x12696340 - 0x12686e50 = 0xF4F0.  No class implements 15676 interfaces.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think my diagram shows what you just described? Say pInterface has value 0x1008, then theobject is at 0x1000; and address 0x1008 holds the address  0x5000 which is the start of the vtable for CoYourClass::IMyInterface. Different instances of the class would have different IMyInterface opinters, e.g. 0x1108 (for object at 0x1100; and address 0x1108 is 0x5000 again.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You are right. I misread the diagram. Failed to appreciate the significance of the star in `(*pInterface) points here`. Please accept my sincere apology.

Answer (score 0):

COM does not require interface pointers in general to point to the same physical object; this is all up to the implementation of each particular COM object. However, the `IUnknown` pointers for any logical object, must be equal, and serve as *object identity*. So you can just `QueryInterface` for `IUnknown` and check that pointer, when you need to check identity.

Comment: Interesting. I'm actually looking for a debugger  solution rather than a code one though - so I can't call QueryInterface from the debugger obviously.  I guess it would be helpful to know how the runtime maps the interface pointer to the implementing object

Comment: @Ben: As I wrote, that's up to the COM object implementation. There is no guaranteed common runtime doing it. It can be completely *ad hoc*.

Comment: @Ben: if you have source code for the object, then you can read it to determine how the object is implemented. If you don't - how exactly are you stepping into the implementation in the debugger?